# Do we have to upgrade to SP2 before upgrading Dynamics AX 4 to AX 2012 R2?

Tags: upgrade, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, ax

We are in the process of planning an upgrade from Ax 4.0 SP1 to AX 2012 R2 (CU 7).

In the Upgrade guide Microsoft "recommends" that you install the newest service pack (For AX 4.0, this would be SP2.)

The client and other internal departments are not to keen to upgrade to SP2 first, mostly because of time constrains.

Does anyone have experience upgrading **Ax 4.0 SP1** to Ax 2012?

If we decide not to upgrade to SP2, what kind of issues problems can we expect later in the upgrade process?

Thanks for any advice!

Tina

Comment: I would ask the programming questions here, and the more system or funcional related questions to the AX community:
https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/135476.aspx

Comment: Thanks. As you can see, I already did. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend it at all.

What "unsupported upgrade path" means is that the `C\ReleaseUpdateDB*` scripts and shadow tables made by Microsoft are specifically not accounting for the data/schema you have.

That pretty much guarantees it won't work unless you investigate and account for the differences.

Upgrading to SP2 would be trivial compared to investigating the potential data loss and inconsistency differences and feeling confident.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, I agree completely. We'll probably still have to investigate and see how it goes. Unfortunately the client would prefer that we spend more time working on our copy of production, than upgrading their actual production system.

Comment: That happens!  I do upgrades all the time and they're different every time.